# pandas: replacing categorical values with counts of multi class label

Tags: python, pandas

Lets assume I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'cat_col': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})
   cat_col  label
0        1      0
1        1      1
2        2      2
3        2      0
4        3      1
5        3      2
```

I want to transform this data frame to the following:

```
cat_col, label, count_when_label_is_0, count_when_label_is_1, count_when_label_is_2
1         0           1,               1,          0
1         1           1,               1,          0
...
```

So basically I add one column for each label value (multinomial label) and for each row I put the count for that label value when the row.cat_col is what it is in that row.  I currently have this but it is very slow:

```
size = df[['cat_col', 'label']].groupby(['cat_col', 'label']).size()
def get_size(cat_val, label_val):
  if label_val in size[cat_val]: return size[cat_val][target_val]
    return 0

for label_val in range(9): # 9 classes in multinominal label
  df['new_col_' + str(label_val)] = df['cat_col'].apply(
      lambda cat_val: get_size(cat_val, label_val))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(index="cat_col", columns="label", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[11]:
label    0  1  2
cat_col
1        1  1  0
2        1  0  1
3        0  1  1
```

Comment: whilst this is different to the OPs, doing this as a tranform (on cat_col) seems very weird...